# Centering a div to the middle of the web page?

Tags: css, html, position, alignment

I want to make my div be positioned in the middle-center part of the web page. I'm attempting to make a pre-loader div which should be in the middle-center part of the web page and after the page loads, that div will be hidden. How can I achieve such?

The div should be centered horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to center a div both hor and ver you could do this way:

markup

```
<div class="centered"></div>
```

css

```
.centered{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/qSvAQ/1/

Comment: This did the trick for me.. Thanks! :) I hope this doesn't break in other browsers beside Firefox though...

Comment: You're welcome.. it works in all browsers ;) IE6 - who cares - too I think (can't test it right now)

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class = 'middle'></div>

.middle{
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer. remember to set your width, if not the div will assume it width is 100% an the center will not show.

Comment: exactly, you can set it according to your liking, 900px is just an example here.

Comment: does this center it vertically as well?

Comment: nop, this is horizontal, vertical align would need absolute positioning. To be sincere, i don't really recommend it unless really needed, but you may want to take a look : http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: I've been waiting 12 years to see this bit of CSS - you can't imagine the sorts of kludges I've had to get into to get things centred in the past. Tsk.

Comment: @SpyrosP why you don't recommend it? What's wrong with an absolute positioned div centered used to show a loader?

Comment: It's not that i do not recommend the technique, there's nothing with it. My problem is that absolute positioning tends to be kinda sloppy and can cause some weird problems if not properly handled. To show a loader, as in your case, it would be pretty fine. Once again, i stress that the technique is just fine.